# Can I specify client ethernet adapter using BSD api?

Tags: macos, socket.io

I am writing simple client side socket commands in Mac OS using basic BSD socket commands - socket(), connect(), write() etc. I can specify the host IP and port and communicate successfully on a LAN ethernet connected to same network. However, when WiFi is enabled this blocks all communications.

Either turning off WiFi or promoting the ethernet adapter to the top of the list in System preferences are not an option. How do I force the client to connect() by specifying the local ethernet adapter?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whatsoever in connecting to a LAN server over Ethernet vs WiFi. The OS and LAN router handle any physical differences for you at the hardware layer, your code does not need to do anything special to handle this.  As long as you have *some* kind of connection to the LAN, whether Ethernet or WiFi, connections can be routed from your client's IP to the server's IP on the LAN as needed.

That being said, if you have both Ethernet and WiFi connections enabled at the same time, and you want to control which adapter is used for a given socket, you can simply `bind()` the socket to the IP address of the desired adapter before calling `connect()`.  If you don't know the IP address, but do know the adapter's interface name, you can use `getifaddrs()` to enumerate the available interfaces, then loop through that list until you find the name you are interested in, and then you will have its IP address.

Comment: So WiFi is enabled on the client, as is an ethernet connection. The ethernet connection is on the same subnet as the server which I wish to connect to but the WiFi is not. If WiFi is enabled and is the first preferred network in System Preferences, the client will not connect to the desired server. If I turn off WiFi or promote the ethernet adapter to first in the System Preferences list, all works fine but this is not an option.

Comment: I was under the impression that the bind function was only applicable to the server side. Can I bind the socket I wish to later write to, to my ethernet IP? And can I then connect to this socket specifying the server IP? I tried but it didn't work. Pseudo code looks like: bind( mySocket, (struct sockaddr*)myIP)) ; connect(mySocket, (struct addr*)server IP))

Comment: If WiFi and Ethernet are both enabled at the same time, the OS should have entries for both of them in its IP routing tables. When trying to connect to the server's IP, the OS should be able to figure out that the server IP matches the Ethernet's network and not the WiFi's network and thus make a connection to the server using the Ethernet network. If that is not happening, then your OS is being stupid. Unless you are on a VPN, the WiFi connection should not be completely hiding the Ethernet connection.

Comment: Yes, you can `bind()` a client socket, `bind()` is not limited to server sockets.  It is perfectly valid to bind a client socket to a specific adapter before calling `connect()`.  If it is not working for you, you are probably not doing it correctly.  Please edit your question to show your actual code, not pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my code which attempts to bind to a socket and then connect to the socket looks like this (excuse lack of error handling). I also set a port on the local adapter to match the server port, i don't know why, I did try random port numbers. I'm not sure what it should be:

```
    // create socket and bind on local adapter
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
bzero(&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(5123);
// now set client IP on prefered interface
inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.95.161.192", &serverAddress.sin_addr);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));


// rewrite socket with server address to connect
(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
bzero(&serverAddress,sizeof(serverAddress));
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(5123);
// now set server IP
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.30.3", &serverAddress.sin_addr);
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));

// write to socket
NSString *str = @"itemset('Away Colour', 'PRIM_RECGLO_MAT', 'genericaway');";
const char *b = [str UTF8String];
write(sockfd, b, strlen(b));
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itemset('genericaway', 'MAT_COLOR', vector4(%f, %f, %f, 1));",self.red2Val,self.green2Val,self.blue2Val];
b = [str UTF8String];
write(sockfd, b, strlen(b));
close(sockfd);
```

Comment: Well you are quite right to say that the OS should perform the appropriate routing across various networks. However I overlooked the fact that the server subnet and the desired client interface are not on the same subnet, and that a central router performs the actual routing. There is no way for the application to know this and it seems that the only attempt made to connect to the server is on the wrong interface. This could be fixed by applying a static route to the client PC's routing table. Nevertheless, binding the client as attempted above would be a good solution but It's not working.